# Visual Studio doesn't let me create new projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, error-handling

I was learning about adding a database created with MS SQL Server to my currency converter. I downloaded both connection happened in the first try. But after I tried to use that project, I started to get errors (if needed I'll add that error, too). And I said "Okay, I still have my code, I can just copy paste to a new project but now VS doesn't let me create new WPF (.NET Framework) projects and throws error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6v4e.png)

Things I tried:

- Delete everything related to VS and MS SQL Server.
- Redownloaded all and installed back.
- Database thing is still working fine but I'm still getting this error. I checked the repos folder. It seems like VS creates the corresponding files according to the project I'm trying to use but all of them are empty and the error is still there.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If Visual Studio is not letting you create a brand new project from scratch, it's time to re-install Visual Studio.

Comment: I did it. I did all the programs I use reinstalled still hasn’t fixed anything

Comment: Any reason you use .NET Framework 4.7.1? That's quite outdated. For new projects, use .NET 8.0 (or at least .NET Framework 4.8).

Comment: Oh, no particular reason. It got installed in that way so I was keeping it. I’ll try to change that and try again thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be some error in .net framework 4.7.1.

You can try to choose a newer version of .net framework when creating WPF (.net framework), such as .net framework 4.8.1.

[image]

Of course, it is recommended that you use WPF directly based on .net 6.0, 7.0 or 8.0

[image]

Or you can use Visual Studio Installer to find .net framework 4.7.1 in Individual components, uninstall it and reinstall it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed help! I've tried all of it but I'm still getting the same error. I'll try to reinstall the program again with the update ideas you gave me.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved? If the problem still persists after reinstalling Visual Studio, please try to open cmd and enter "dotnet --info", and edit the screenshot of the running results into your case.